# While using npm command I'm facing this warning? how to resolve it?

Tags: angular, angularjs, npm, npm-install

npm WARN config key `key` and `cert` are no longer used for most registry operations.
npm WARN config Use registry scoped `keyfile` and `certfile` instead.
npm WARN config     Example:
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:keyfile=/path/to/key.pem
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:certfile=/path/to/cert.crt
npm WARN config key `key` and `cert` are no longer used for most registry operations.
npm WARN config Use registry scoped `keyfile` and `certfile` instead.
npm WARN config     Example:
npm WARN config     //other-registry.tld/:keyfile=/path/to/key.pem
npm WARN config     /

Someone please help me to resolve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBqQn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that there is folder 'npm' in path -> C:\Users"yourUserName"\AppData\Roaming. I tried that in nodejs.
Note: npm is an empty folder.